# OneToMany invalid Mapping

Tags: doctrine-orm

i am trying to create a oneToMany relationship. Since Doctrine only offers ManyToOne Unidirectional im using that. Somehow the validation of the mapping fails and I am not able to spot my mistake:

Validation Error:

> [Mapping]  FAIL - The entity-class 'Strego\TippBundle\Entity\BetRound'
>   mapping is invalid:
>   * The association Strego\TippBundle\Entity\BetRound#userStatus refers to the owning side field
>   Strego\TippBundle\Entity\UserBetRoundStatus#betRound which does not
>   exist.

My First Entity (BetRound):

```
<?php 
namespace Strego\TippBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection as Collection;
use Strego\AppBundle\Entity\Base as BaseEntity;


/**
 * Strego\TippBundle\Entity\BetRound
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class BetRound extends BaseEntity {

    //......

    /**
     *
     * @var Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="UserBetRoundStatus", mappedBy="betRound", cascade={"all"})
     */
    protected $userStatus;

}
```

My related Entity(UserBetRoundStatus)

```
<?php
namespace Strego\TippBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Strego\AppBundle\Entity\Base as BaseEntity;

/**
 * Strego\TippBundle\Entity\Game
 *
 * @ORM\Table
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"user", "betRound"}, message="Unique Entity Validator Fails for UserStatus", groups="unique")
 * 
 */
class UserBetRoundStatus extends BaseEntity {
    // .....

    /*
     * @var BetRound
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BetRound", inversedBy="userStatus")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="betround_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    protected $betRound;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the issue:

```
/**  <---------  you need two *
 * @var BetRound
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BetRound", inversedBy="userStatus")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="betround_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotNull()
 */
protected $betRound;
```